# Model Derivative API's - Istance Properties

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-inventor

I'm using Model Derivative API's to upload Inventor's IAM on a bucket (in a zip mode). I'm using Inventor 2022 and Instance Properties. Is it possible to publish SVF/SVF2 file to have instance properties values on a Forge Viewer?

I just tried, but I only have custom properties and not instance properties (see pictures).

TIA
Alder

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, instance properties are not exported to SVF, so they won't show up in the Viewer.

I logged a ticket to request support for this: INVGEN-62516

Comment: any news about the ticket?

Comment: No deadline yet 